# How do I let each control in a listbox set its own height and then mirror this height to all other items in the listbox?

Tags: silverlight, xaml, data-binding

Seems like it should be simple, but I'm stumped!

I have a listbox with multiple instances of MyControl in it (via data binding to an ObserveableCollection).

A MyControl is able to set its height (based on stuff that happens inside it).

I'd like EVERY instance of MyControl in the listbox to grow and shrink when ANY of the other instances changes its own height. ie: they all have the same height always.

Like I said - seems like it should be simple, but I've gotten myself tangled in a web of events, properties and bindings, and I can't seem to find a simple example of how to do this effectively. When I put a single MyControl on a page, it can resize itself perfectly. Just not in a listbox. Thanks!!

Comment: put your control inside a scrollviewer and see if it can still resize correctly.

Comment: not sure how that will help me? I can scroll all the controls (no matter what size they are) in the listbox. The issue is how to synchronise the height across multiple items in the listbox.

Comment: Which of the items is in charge? The largest? The latest changed?

Comment: the latest changed. all changes then apply to all other controls in the list.

Answer (score 0):

Set the ItemsPanelTemplate to a subclass of Panel that lays out its children according to your own algorithm.